# Twitter Userstream OAuth via fails with HTTP 404

Tags: twitter-oauth, phirehose

My app uses the small and simple phirehose PHP library (UserstreamPhirehose.php) to consume a Twitter user stream (for a single account). It stopped working over the last 24 hours and when I try to reconnect this bit fails:

POST [stuff] to https://userstream.twitter.com/2/user.json
Returns HTTP 404 Not Found

Any ideas what may be causing it? A quick google search doesn't reveal any obvious causes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For some reason in my version of Phirehose, the URL_BASE (in the constructor of the Phirehose class in Phirehose.php, line 187 in my file) was set as to 'https://userstream.twitter.com/2/';

according to twitter docs, the official version is 1.1 - not 2.

Funny thing is until now '/2/' worked, but over the past 24 hours (or between 2-3pm eastern time yesterday), someone at twitter made it unavailable and it now generates a HTTP 404.

So if you're having the same problem replace the line in Phirehose.php which reads:

case self::METHOD_USER:$this->URL_BASE = 'https://userstream.twitter.com/2/';break;

with:

case self::METHOD_USER:$this->URL_BASE = 'https://userstream.twitter.com/1.1/';break;

and Phirehose will continue pumping again!